# What are some popular distance measuring techniques between images?

Tags: image, graphics, computer-vision

In machine learning, a lot of techniques require defining a metric between different data points. I want to know what are some popular metrics when the data are images.

An obvious way of measuring distance between images is to sum up the squares of pixel errors. But this is sensitive to simple transformations like translation. For example, even shifting the whole image by one pixel could result in a large distance.

What are some other distance measuring techniques that is more compatible with translation, rotations, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Wasserstein distance(earth mover's distance) and kullback leibler divergence are the two that I have come across while studying literature about Generative Adversarial Networks(GANs).